# What countries will accept a comfortably-retired US couple for permanent resident status?

Tags: immigration

We were blown away that we could not flee to Canada to live, even though we have substantial resources.  Canada only allows working immigrants.  Are there other countries that would take us? We are not interested in Central America.

Comment: With enough money, you can "buy" your way into a lot of places. For example, if you have NZ$10 million (only about US$6.5 million!) to invest, you can apply for an [Investor 1 Resident Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/investor-plus-investor-1-resident-visa) for New Zealand. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Try googling "buying citizenship". Portugal 250k USD apparently.

Comment: According to https://www.businessinsider.com/countries-where-you-can-buy-citizenship-residency-or-passport-2018-9 there are quite a few options, depending on what resources you have and whether you want residency or citizenship. Turkey, Greece, Portugal, Montenegro, various Caribbean countries, Cyprus, and the UK are amongst those listed.

Comment: If you can afford two homes, you can spend just under six months a year in Canada and the rest of your time in your other home.  This is popular among Canadian retirees, where they spend just under half of each year, usually the winter half, in Florida or Hawaii or somewhere else with warmer weather.

Comment: "Flee" to Canada? The U.S isn't exactly at war on home soil. Maybe you should decide on where you want to go first, rather than just 'anywhere but the U.S'